# Is there a way to find all hidden elements that have text using selenium python

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape all translated text from multiple webpages.
The page has to translate fully before I start the scraping and in order to do that I have to scroll through the page. I am using selenium with Edge and it translate feature.
The problem here is that it only translates text that is visible and there are some text that dont show until some buttons are pressed.

This is my code:

```
        options = EdgeOptions()
        options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
        options.use_chromium = True
        options.add_extension('adblock.crx')
        capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.EDGE
        prefs = {
        "translate_whitelists": {input_lang:output_lang},
        "translate":{"enabled":"true"}}

        options.add_argument('--lang=en')
        options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

        driver = Edge(executable_path=PATH, options=options, desired_capabilities=capabilities)
        driver.maximize_window()

        driver.get(url)
       
        # This is to scroll through the page
        if input_lang != output_lang:
            total_height = int(driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight"))
            divisions = total_height // 20

            for i in range(1, total_height, divisions):
                driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {});".format(i))
                time.sleep(3)
            driver.execute_script(f"window.scrollTo(0, {total_height});")
            time.sleep(4)
```

Is there a way I can find all hidden element with text and loop click through them so they become visible?
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use `element.getAttribute("textContent")` instead of `getText()`

`getText()` uses `innerText` and considers the element display property, if its not displayed , then no content will be retrieved

While `textContent` doesn't care whether the element is displayed , it retries the content as it is

Comment: Thanks but is there a way to make all hidden text visible? because I need to translate it and edge can't translate what is not visible

Comment: @Demaxl - `browser.execute_script('arguments[0].style.display = "inherit";', element)` or other display options such as `block`

Comment: glad to hear it!